# How are certain model attributes populated when its methods are called?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here's a model describing my UserFriendship model, a model whose attributes are used to create a join table between two users who are friends.

```
class UserFriendship < ActiveRecord::Base


    #attributes: ["id", "friend_id", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "state"]

    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :friend, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'friend_id'

    def send_accept_email
        UserNotifier.friend_accepted(id).deliver    
    end

end
```

Now the one thing I'm concerned about here is that `id` variable inside the `send_accept_email` method. I just have no idea what it means or how I can change it.

I have a model_spec that tests this model like so (using rspec):

```
it "should send a friend_accepted email" do
        @user_1 = FactoryGirl.create(:user_with_all_valid)
        @user_2 = FactoryGirl.create(:user_with_all_valid_two)

        # much prefer " user_id: @user_1.id " to 'magic' "user: @user_1"

        @user_friendship = UserFriendship.create user_id: @user_1.id, friend_id: @user_2.id

       expect{@user_friendship.send_accept_email}.to change{ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size}.from(0).to(1)
end
```

and it passes, so actionmailer's sending en email okay. But I just don't understand how that spec is populating the `id` variable with 1.

If I wanted to use this method with a state machine, and wanted to send the `send_accept_email` to a user outside of a spec, surely I'd have to change the method like this to pass in the parameter:

```
    def send_accept_email(specified_id)
            UserNotifier.friend_accepted(specified_id).deliver  
    end
```

and call it like this:

```
    UserFriendship.send_accept_email(76)
```

Or is it something to do with this (how it's actually called in the spec):

```
@user_friendship.send_accept_email
```

The way the method is chained to an instance of the UserFriendship class. When you do this, is the `id` variable in the model automatically populated when `send_accept_email` (or any other model method) is called? Are the other model attributes, automatically populated also, so I have variables such as `friend_id`, `user_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `state` all set to `@user_friendship`'s attributes when I call it like this:

```
@user_friendship.send_accept_email
```

Could someone explain this slowly please?

Answer (score 1):

The `id` is the id of a record in the UserFriendship table.

You can't use `UserFriendship.send_accept_email` because it is an instance method and not a class method. Hence you will have to call it on instances(UserFriendship objects) of the model.

`id` is auto-populated because it is interpreted as `self.id`. So if one of your UserFriendship objects looks like 
`<#UserFriendship id:100, user_id:131, friend_id:213, created_at:...>`, `self.id` or just `id` inside an instance method will return `100`.

Hope I got the point across.

Answer (score 0):

akagr is correct, when you ask

> Now the one thing I'm concerned about here is that id variable inside the send_accept_email method. I just have no idea what it means or how I can change it.

the id is that of the UserFriendship instance. What you haven't showed us is `UserNotifier.friend_accepted(id)` and what it does with the UserFriendShip instance's id.

Hopefully it uses the `user_id` to find the appropriate user's email address. If it's looking up the user using the id passed to `friend_accepted`, it will be finding the wrong user.